# length of string not what I thought it would be

Tags: bash, awk

I have a string in a "test.txt" file:

`207.46.13.136 - - [22/Jan/2019:03:56:21 +0330] "GET /product/30649?model=60398 HTTP/1.1" 200 41198 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" "-"`

I executed:

`grep 'GET /product/*' test.txt | awk -F "/" '{ if ( "${#5}" -lt 6 ) {print $5} } '`

So it should output all strings at `$5` that have lengths less than 6.

I expected no output as the length of my `$5` is 22 (`30649?model=60398 HTTP`) but it outputted that string anyway.

EDIT: I found that the length of `"30649?model=60398 HTTP"` is 0!! I'm more confused.

What's happening?

Comment: THANKS! I'm a noob, I didn't know that length() was a thing

Comment: You're welcome - please take a look at the very thorough answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up shell and `awk` syntax here.

`sh` (or `bash`) and `awk` are two interpreters for two different languages that have nothing to do with each other.

The syntax of `awk` is very C-like.

In `awk`, variables are referenced with `var`, not `$var` like in shells, and `$` in `awk` is a unary operator to retrieve the value of an input field (or the full record if applied to 0). `$ (3 + 3)` for instance retrieves the value of the 6th field. There is no variable interpolation inside string constants in `awk`, let alone interpretation of operators, whether it's unary `-`, `+` or `$`.

So in `awk`, `"${#5}"` is just the string constant with literal value `${#5}`.

`"${#5}" -lt`, same as `"string" - lt` is the binary `-` operator applied to that string and the `lt` variable. Because it's an arithmetic operator, both operands are converted to numbers. Since neither start with anything that looks like a number that yields `0 - 0`, so 0.

Then the (invisible) concatenation operator is used. In `x y`, `x` and `y` are converted to string and concatenated resulting in a new string. So `"${#5}" -lt 6` which is `("${#5}" - lt) 6` results in the `"06"` string.

```bsh
$ gawk 'BEGIN{result = "${#5}" -lt 6; print typeof(result) ": " result}'
string: 06
```

That's used as the `if` condition where true is either a non-0 number or a non-empty string, so here we always get *true* since `"06"` is a non-empty string.

The correct `awk` syntax here would be:

```bsh
awk -F "/" '{ if (length($5) < 6) print $5 }'
```

Or using the more canonical *`<condition> {<action>}`* pattern:

```bsh
awk -F/ 'length($5) < 6 {print $5}'
```

Also note that `grep 'GET /product/*'` looks for `GET /product` followed by any number (including 0) of `/` characters, so it's functionally equivalent to `grep 'GET /product'`. `awk` being a superset of `grep`, you generally also don't need to pipe them together. So here:

```bsh
awk -F/ 'index($0, "GET /product/") && length($5) < 6 {print $5}'
```

Where `index($0, "string")` to locate `string` in the full record (`$0`) would be the equivalent of `grep -F 'GET /product/'`. See also `/regexp/` (short for `$0 ~ /regexp/`) for an equivalent of `grep -E regexp`.